# Are »an die Seite« and »zur Seite« the same?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase

> Man hat Schränke und Regale abgebaut und die Teile ***an die Seite*** gestellt.

Can we use "zur Seite" instead here, and, if not, why?

Answer (score 3):

### In a nutshell:

**an die Seite**
To put something close to the side of something else, i.e. you move it to a certain place.

**zur Seite**
To put something aside, i.e. you move it away from where it was before.

**beiseite**
This is a synonym for »zur Seite«.

---

### an die Seite

> Der Kamin war mit Möbeln verbaut, man konnte die Vorderseite des Kamins gar nicht sehen, aber an seiner Seite war ein freier Platz.
>   *Man hat Schränke und Regale abgebaut und die Teile **an die Seite** gestellt.*
>   Jetzt ist der Zugang zum Kamin frei, und an seiner Seite stören die Teile nicht.

This means:

> The fireplace was fitted with furniture, you couldn't see the front of the fireplace, but there was free space at it's side.
>   *They dismantled the cabinets and shelfs and put the parts **on the side.***
>   Now the way to the fireplace is free, and the parts don't bother on its side.

---

### zur Seite, beiseite

> Helga und Otto ziehen aus ihrer alten Wohnung aus, und haben Möbelpacker beauftragt, die Möbel abzutransportieren.
>   *Man hat Schränke und Regale abgebaut und die Teile **zur Seite** gestellt.*
>   *Man hat Schränke und Regale abgebaut und die Teile **beiseite** gestellt.*
>   Als Otto in der neuen Wohnung die Möbel wieder zusammenbauen wollte, stellte er fest, dass einige der Teile beschädigt waren.

This means:

> Helga and Otto are moving out of their old apartment, and they hired movers to move the furniture.
>   *They dismantled the cabinets and shelfs and put the parts **aside.***
>   When Otto wanted to reassemble the furniture, he realized, that some of the parts was damaged.

---

»Zur Seite« also has another meaning, but it doesn't fit in your context. This meaning is:

> Sie bekommen **einen Paten zur Seite gestellt**, der Sie in allen Fragen unterstützen wird.
>
> You will **receive a mentor**, who will support you in all matters.

In this case you also use »beiseite« instead of »zur Seite«, but »zur Seite« sounds better.